# Requesting airdrop of SOL on devnet or testnet throws error, rate limit is reached, even though I never reached the rate limit in the first place

Tags: rpc, devnet, error, testnet, airdrop

[image: Error using Devnet.]

I currently only have 0.623 SOL on this account, and I have not requested more than 24 sol per day/ 2 sol per airdrop, so I don't understand why it says "rate limit reached".

How can I fix this problem?

I can't airdrop something on testnet nor on devnet, I always get this "airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached" Error.

I want to deploy my first anchor program and I can't airdrop myself enough sol to do it, neither can anchor deploy finalize any tx on devnet, I can't even use the solfaucet, every tx fails!.

My Solana CLI version is 1.13.5. The rpc URL i use is: https://api.devnet.solana.com and the websocket url is wss://api.devnet.solana.com.

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your Public Network IP address gets changed whenever you restart your WiFi router or switch to a different network. Since, most of the faucet/airdrop APIs are conditioned and developed in such a way that, It doesn't allow the same IP/User to Airdrop too frequently due to prevent misuse of the service.

Either wait some time, Restart the WiFi router, or switch to a different Network.

Answer (score 1):

Switching Wifi Routers fixed the issue for me, I have no idea why.

Comment: Same here, can someone pls explain why? 

Comment: No idea, man, this is so weird to me. I always have to switch routers for me to be able to develop, probably some wifi settings? Or a different IP address?

Comment: You were likely rate limited

Answer (score 0):

[image: Error using solfaucet]

Here is my trying to airdrop 2 sol on solfaucet

Answer (score 0):

Faucets are handled by RPCs. Instead of using default devnet RPC you can go ahead and grab a Helius API key to use their RPC & faucet to grab that juicy 2 SOL.

Helius dashboard: https://dev.helius.xyz/dashboard/app

You are almost certainly rate limited due to previous airdrops. Limit is 24 a day AND 2 per hour on https://api.devnet.solana.com

You can use VPN to switch your IP address. Reseting the router is not guaranteed to change the IP because it might be a static one (e.g. if you're in the office)